# How to get an entry permit for Myanmar in Mae Sai?

Tags: thailand, paperwork, permits, myanmar, thai-citizens

While doing research for an [upcoming visa run to Myanmar](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/31506/82), I was directed to [a Wikivoyage article](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Tachileik) that indicates that Thai citizens can enter Myanmar without a passport:

> If you are a Thai citizen, you can get a temporary border pass at the Immigration office about 2 km before the border on Pahonyotin Rd in Mae Sai for 30 baht. All you need is your bat prachachon (ID card).

This would be awesome, as it just so happens I'll have a Thai citizen accompanying me, and I bet she'd have a lot more fun exploring Tachileik with me than having to wait on the Thai side for me to clear immigration (:

Where is this immigration office, and what is the process that she will need to go through to get her temporary border pass?

Comment: The immigration office is apparently [here](https://maps.google.com/maps/ms?msa=0&msid=214923170432669428134.000465f03d84d91df360b&ie=UTF8&t=m&vpsrc=6&ll=20.430703,99.88541&spn=0.008114,0.006641&z=17&iwloc=0004662013f19e9a20a84&dg=feature).

Answer (score 2):

The Thai citizen needs to go the municipal office in Mae Sai.  To the right of the main building is a small building that issues the permit.  There is signage in Thai that will guide your friend to the correct window. I am not sure of the fee, but I think it is around 40 baht.